# Copy content of zipfile in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking to recursively search through a network directory to identify all `.xls` files in the `zip` files. For each `XLS` file found in the `zip` file, I would like to copy it out to a local location in `C:`. Here is my script so far:

```
import os
import zipfile
import fnmatch
import shutil

rootPath = "L:\Data\Cases"
destPath = "C:\Test"
allFileList = []
zipList = []

# Create a list containing all files contained within L:\Data\Cases
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in filenames:
        allFileList.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

# Return a list of filepaths containing zipfiles.
for file in allFileList:
    if file.endswith(".zip"):
        zipList.append(file)

for file in zipList:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as zip_file:
        for member in zip_file.namelist():
            if member.endswith(".xls"):
                filename = os.path.basename(member)
                if not filename:
                    continue
                source = zip_file.open(member)
                target = os.path.join(destPath, filename)
                shutil.copy2(source, target)
```

The error code is below. I think the error is being caused by copying what is in effect a file in a compressed container to the target path.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/parsecsv.py", line 30, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(source, target)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python278\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python278\lib\shutil.py", line 68, in copyfile
    if _samefile(src, dst):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python278\lib\shutil.py", line 63, in _samefile
    return (os.path.normcase(os.path.abspath(src)) ==
  File "C:\Program Files\Python278\lib\ntpath.py", line 487, in abspath
    path = _getfullpathname(path)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `rootPath = "L:\Data\"` will make last " (double quote) escape character.

Comment: Can you edit and show the error ? It would help.

Comment: Edited with slight change and latest error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by bruno I think you can't check a zipfile content but I think a cleaner way can be removing them after extraction therefore you can use shutil.rmtree to remove the other stuff.

```
def main():
rootPath = "C:\\rootpath"
destPath = "C:\\Test"
allFileList = []
zipList = []
# Create a list containing all files contained within L:\Data\Cases
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in filenames:
        allFileList.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

# Return a list of filepaths containing zipfiles.
for file in allFileList:
    if file.endswith(".zip"):
        zipList.append(file)


for file in zipList:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as zip_file:
        for member in zip_file.namelist():
            if member.endswith(".xls"):
                zip_file.extract(member, destPath)

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(destPath):
    for filename in filenames:
        if not filename.endswith(".xls"):
            shutil.rmtree(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

`ZipFile.open()` doesn't return a filesystem path but a file-like `ZipExtFile` object. What you want is `ZipFile.extract()` (and then you don't need `shutil.copy()` at all):

```
# NB : untested code, refer to the doc for more infos
for file in zipList:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as zip_file:
        for member in zip_file.namelist():
            if member.endswith(".xls"):
                zip_file.extract(member, destPath)
```

Also and FWIW, you don't need to first build a list of all files then build a list of zipfile then iterate on this list - you can as well do the whole thing in one pass:

```
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in filenames:
        if not filename.endswith(".zip"):
            continue 
        fullpath = os.path.join(dirname, filename))
        with zipfile.ZipFile(fullpath) as zip_file:
            for member in zip_file.namelist():
                if member.endswith(".xls"):
                    zip_file.extract(member, destPath)
```

Comment: Many thanks @bruno for the help. The above works great but it extracts the folder structure containing the xls file. Is there anyway it can simply extract the xls file without the folder structure? Thanks

Comment: Not directly AFAICT. If you don't care about the file's metadata (times etc) you can `ZipFile.open()` it then write it's content to a newly created file. Else, you'll have to first extract the file to a temporary destination then `shutil.move()` it to it's desired destination.